# Install Realtek 8152 or 8153 drivers on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, dell, realtek

I've got a Dell XPS 13 9360 Developer Edition (Ubuntu 16.10). I'd like to use an ethernet adapter. I've bought a Dell Dock WD15 and a DA200 but I can't get the ethernet connection to work.

When I connect the USB-C cable, these devices show up in the `lsusb` list:

DA200:

> Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

WD 15:

> Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

How can I get this ethernet adapter working? Do I need to install extra drivers?

I've tested both devices with a Dell Latitude 7275 and Windows 10 and they're working fine.

Update: results from `dmesg | grep -i r815`:

```
[   12.656121] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[   13.438331] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Using pass-thru MAC addr d4:81:d7:22:ec:02
[   13.494047] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 eth0: v1.08.6
[   13.666848] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd481d722ec02: renamed from eth0
[  540.891031] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Using pass-thru MAC addr d4:81:d7:22:ec:02
[  540.944670] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 eth0: v1.08.6
[  542.486406] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enxd481d722ec02: renamed from eth0
[ 1223.991503] usbcore: deregistering interface driver r8152
[ 1224.656988] r8152: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 1224.657054] r8152: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 1224.824563] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 eth0: v2.08.0 (2016/12/09)
[ 1224.824568] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
[ 1224.825680] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[ 1224.826492] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enx847beb33f1dd: renamed from eth0
[ 1415.312339] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: v2.08.0 (2016/12/09)
[ 1415.312345] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
[ 1427.261311] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: v2.08.0 (2016/12/09)
[ 1427.261316] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
[ 1429.002364] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 enx00249b2352c9: renamed from eth0
[ 1564.756280] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Unknown version 0x7cf0
[ 1564.756286] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Unknown Device
[ 1629.207955] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 eth0: v2.08.0 (2016/12/09)
[ 1629.207960] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
[ 1631.014946] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enx847beb33f1dd: renamed from eth0
[ 6101.594643] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: v2.08.0 (2016/12/09)
[ 6101.594649] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 eth0: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
[ 6103.232845] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 enx00249b2352c9: renamed from eth0
```

Output from `dmesg | grep enx`:

```
[   13.259620] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enx847beb33f1dd: renamed from eth0
[  177.044463] r8152 4-1.4:1.0 enx00249b2352c9: renamed from eth0
```

Comment: The driver `r8152` is included by default in Ubuntu 16.10. Please insert that device and check the log for informative messages: `dmesg | grep -i r815` Next, edit your question to include the result.

Comment: So far, so good! You have an ethernet interface enx00249b2352c9. Is there any sign of an ethernet connection in Network Manager? Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep enx` In fact, *both* devices are driven by this same driver!

Comment: No sign of an ethernetconnection. I've added the output from `dmesg`.

Comment: Let's dig deeper: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e enx -e etwork | tail -n25` As the output will be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com My next replies will be delayed about 2 1/2 hours.

Comment: @chili555 http://paste.ubuntu.com/24275482/. I reconnected the WD15 at 18:17:18.

Comment: No idea if it's relevant info, but I pasted the output of `lshw -C network` and `ip addr` here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24276838/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56262/discussion-between-chili555-and-stephan-vierkant).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to get the driver working on Debian Stretch:

1) Download official driver from realtek: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software

2) untar it: `# tar xvf ./r8152.53.56-2.12.0.tar`

3) make sure you have current kernel headers installed `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

4) compile the driver `cd r8152_2.12.0 && make`

5) install the compiled driver `sudo make install`

Comment: Realtek says "USB LAN LINUX driver for kernel up to 4.15." E.g. Ubuntu 19.10 uses 5.3.0. Have you tried that with a 5.x kernel?

Comment: `No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72` on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: AFAIK at the time of writing I was running debian 10 stable with kernel 4.19. Realtek either supplies drivers for newer kernel (you need to go and search for it) or it does not and then you can search for some open source driver and you may get lucky.

Comment: Worked for me on 16.04 for the monitor Phillips 346B1C when using it as a docking station.

Comment: Good answer. A bit of supplementary explanation. 1. don't forget to run `depmod -a` and `update-initramfs -u`.  2. copy rule to udev rules folder.